# Number keyboard for python-telegram-bot

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I am currently creating a telegram bot using python-telegram-bot. For some questions in the bot I need a number keyboard displayed to the user. I tried:

```
number_keys = [
               ['7', '8', '9'],
               ['4', '5', '6'],
               ['1', '2', '3'],
                    ['0']
              ]
    
number_keyboard = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(number_keys)
```

Unfortunately the user can only input one digit, but I want also multidigit numbers to be possible. Do you have any suggestions?

Thank you in advance,

Sören

Answer (score 1):

Use [InlineKeyboardButton](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.inlinekeyboardbutton.html) instead and update message with values using `edit_text` or `edit_reply_markup` to show what was already typed.